# Add swift extension to swift package

Tags: swift, xcode, package

I want to move swift extension files into a swift package. But, after moving files to swift package, I have got this kind of error:

> "Type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'makeUnderlineString'"

Can't we add a swift extension into a swift package?

**Updated:**

Finally, I have solved the issue. I missed several things. These are steps to use extensions in Swift Package. Thanks all for your comments.

1. Add "public" in front of the "extension"

> public extension String {

2. If you edit the Swift Package in local, create a scheme for the Swift Package.
3. Add the Swift Package into `TARGET -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`.
4. Import the target of the Swift Package. This `MyLibrary` is a target name in Swift Package.

> import MyLibrary

Comment: Did you make the extension `public`?

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Are you using it in a test target? My first guess was what @Sweeper said. Always write at least one test per-extension, without `@testable` to guarantee that won't happen!

Comment: Thanks all, especially Sweeper. I have updated the question with the solutions I found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project **CMD+Shift+K**, then, if "public"-keyword is used where necessary, it should work.